# NSDate Off By One Day

Tags: iphone, ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

in an iPhone app I'm currently developing, I'm having some issues with regard to dates. I don't make extensive use of them, so this is pretty basic, but I'm somehow still doing it wrong. When I take my NSDate in through a simple Month/Day/Year UIDatePicker, I'll select say December 24, 2011 for example. However, when I print out the NSDate according to the local time zone via an NSDateFormatter, I'll get a MM-DD-YY output that is a day less than the day I selected. Here is all of my relevant date input/output code:

I'm taking in a date associated with a custom object via a UIDatePicker with the following methods:

```
- (void)willPresentActionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet // Protocol method for UIActionSheetDelegate
{

// Among other things, add our UIDatePicker to a UIActionSheet that we pop up.

NSDate* currentDate = [NSDate date];

[pickerView setDate:currentDate];

[pickerView setMaximumDate:currentDate];

[pickerView setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeDate]; // We don't need time for this.

}

- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex 
{ // UIActionSheetDelegate Protocol method for saving date change if OK is selected, else if cancel is selected, do nothing.

    [self.customObjectBeingInput setDate:[ourDatePicker date]]; // Set object date to selected date in date picker.
}
```

As far as outputting the date to a UILabel I have setup, here is what's going on there:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateformatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]; // Format the date into human-readble format.
    [dateformatter setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yyyy"];
    [dateformatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
    [dateformatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
    NSString *formattedDate = [dateformatter stringFromDate:[self.customObject date]];
    [[self.customViewController customObjectDateLabel] setText:formattedDate];
    [dateformatter release];
    dateformatter = nil;
```

Am I supposed to be setting something related to time zones for the `UIDatePicker` input, or since an `NSDate` returns an absolute point in time regardless of the user's time zone, we can generally ignore locality issues, at least in the *input* stage?

I definitely think this has to do with the output stage and not with how I'm taking in the date through the `UIDatePicker`, but I'm at a loss as to what I'm doing wrong or not doing at all.

Comment: A couple of questions: Is your date picker instantiated in code or IB? What is your time zone / locale?

Comment: All instantiated in code and my time zone/locale is Eastern Time. Thanks.

Comment: i'm not sure, perhaps set the timeZone property on the UIDatePicker ? default (nil) sets it to localTimeZone, and in your NSDateFormatter you are using systemTimeZone.. [Apple Doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIDatePicker_Class/Reference/UIDatePicker.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDatePicker/timeZone)

Comment: Please give us a concrete example. NSLog the date you get from the date picker and give us the output for that date that the date formatter generates. You should also verify that `+systemTimeZone` indeed represents the time zone you expect and that the date formatter indeed uses the same date that you get from the date picker.

Comment: So it looks like in my infinite wisdom I left in a piece of code tucked away that was really calculating a new date based on a GMT difference. That problem now appears to be solved after taking that code out. NSLog's are both "Unformatted Date: Wednesday, December 14, 2011 12:00:00 AM Eastern Standard Time" now. However, I am utilizing a Calendar view from the Tapku library and those cells are  being filled in with a date the day AFTER the date being entered... Probably a similar issue, I should get it soon. Thanks.

Comment: Yup, the library was using a secondsFromGMT:0 method instead of NSTimeZone localTimeZone. Now all dates show up correctly, whoo-hoo.